# How to display the screen of one player to all other players in Godot ,gdscript?

Tags: game-development, multiplayer, lan, godot, gdscript

I'm using Godot engine to develop a multiplayer Lan WiFi game,at some point the game will give a player a task to solve ,the task is a mini game that has some random aspects ,one player should control and solve this task while other players will be just watching and should not be able to control anything ,so I want to know how to display exactly what's happening on that player screen to the rest of players?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJylN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would recommend is to record the person game screen and just send the recording to the other person via live this is going to take some bandwidth tho
(https://github.com/henriquelalves/GodotRecorder)
also when sending a screen recording it just a matrix array or a pool byte array in Godot i think.

another way is to get person movement and location and set the camera to that exact location you could also just use two cameras and a split screen to see the current player and the other player.

Comment: Thanks ,but can you tell how to send texture through RPC call?

Comment: What I'll recommend is the get player b location Wich should be a Vector 2d then send this info to player A and player A should hav another camera and set the second camera of player b location also I recommend building a peer to peer chatting project to understand the basics of networking